# Class objects (instances) into dictionary in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I would like to create multiple instances of the Product Class and convert each instance as a new item in a dictionary.

I'm not pretty sure how to append the new object and its attribute values to the dictionary

This is my class:

```py
class Product():
    def __init__(self, id, name, descr):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.descr = descr
```

This is the part that creates the `Product` objects and inserts them into the dictionary:

```py
addProductToDict(id, name, descr, product_dict):

    new_product = Product(id, name, descr)

    # insert new product instance into dict
    product_dict <--- new_product ### pseudo code

    return product_dict

    
product_dict = {} 

while True:
    print(" Give the products id, name and description")
    id = input("Give id: ")
    name = input("Give name: ")
    descr = input("Give descr: ")

    product_dict = addProductToDict(id, name, descr, product_dict)
```

Desired dictionary format:

```py
my_dict = {'1': {'id': '1', 'name': 'TestName1', 'descr': 'TestDescription1'}, '2': {'id': '2', 'name': 'TestName2', 'descr': 'TestDescription2'}, '3': {'id': '3', 'name': 'TestName3', 'descr': 'TestDescription3'}}
```

Comment: I am not quite following what you want the structure of the dictionary to be. You can't just append an object. You could create an entry with a key:value where the value is the object but it is unclear what you want the key to be.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify the end result.

Comment: So if you have multiple objects, what do you expect your dictionary to be like?

Comment: Do you want to *unpack* the object into the dictionary? The desired output shows that, but "store each instance as a new item in a dictionary" would mean something different. What is the desired result for *two* objects?

Comment: Correct. The word "store" might cause some confusion. I edited my code to give more context. The end result should add each Object instance into the dictionary.

Comment: The question still only shows a format that is unambiguous for a *single* object. Please add the desired result for *two* objects.

Comment: Added the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your desired output, I have modified my answer.

```python
pprint(vars(new_product))

class Product():
    def __init__(self, id, name, descr):
        self.name = name
        self.id= id
        self.descr= descr

product_dict = {} 
new_product = Product(1, 'Test Name', 'Test Description')
product_dict = pprint(vars(new_product))
```

This will give you the desired format but I think you will have issues if you have more than one item in your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to store them in a list instead of a dictionary, unless you have a key for each object

```
products = []
products.append(Product(1, 'Test Name', 'Test Description'))
```

##### edit

so, if you have a key

```
products = {}
_id = 1
products[_id] = Product(_id, 'Test Name', 'Test Description')
```

Comment: I have a key for each one the `id` attribute.